# Editing the year in date field in EXTJS 4.0 is defaulting the year to 2020

Tags: extjs4.2

I have a date field in a form

```
        xtype: 'datefield',
        id: 'dateId',           
        maskRe: /[0-9\/]/,
        format   : 'm/d/Y',
```

for ex - if the date populated in that field is 07/30/2014. now i want to manually edit the date, if i give two backspaces, which means 07/30/20. and then click some where in the form, the year is getting defaulted to 07/30/2020. how to stop this getting defaulted to that 2020 year.

Comment: 07/30/20 is equivalent to 07/30/2020. This is expected and normal behavior. When a year is only two digits, it is always the last two digits, so 20 == 2020, 00 == 2000, 14 == 2014, etc.

Comment: this is happening when the date in datefield does not start with 0 i.e 01,02,03..meaning when it is 08/08/2014, giving two backspaces to year, is not defaulting it to 2020...When it is 08/10/2014...then giving two backspaces to year, is defaulting it to 2020 why is it behaving like that?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in my comment, but I will try to expand on that comment as much as possible, and make it as clear as possible. Here is the original comment:

"07/30/20 is equivalent to 07/30/2020. This is expected and normal behavior. When a year is only two digits, it is always the last two digits, so 20 == 2020, 00 == 2000, 14 == 2014, etc."

So, let me step you through an example.

- You type `08/08/2014` into the datefield.
- Hit backspace twice, removing the `1` and the `4`.
- Now you have `08/08/20`.
- When writing dates, the year can be written as 2 digits or 4. If written as two, the last two digits are used. So, the year 20 is the same as the year 2020.
- The datefield has logic to handle 2 digit dates, so it knows that `08/08/20` is actually `08/08/2020`.

That is why when you have `08/08/20` in a datefield, it interprets it as `08/08/2020`.

Comment: when i have 08/08/20 in a datefield, it is not interpreting it as 08/08/2020. instead it is saying tooltip as "08/08/20 is not a valid date, it must be in the format m/d/Y

Comment: That is COMPLETELY different than what you said in your original question, and in your first comment. You said it was defaulting 08/08/20 to 08/08/2020. You said NOTHING about a tooltip indicating it as an invalid date. If that is indeed to actual issue you are dealing with, you should delete this question and make a new one, explaining the real issue you are having.